# Is there a general template for Proving the Irrationality of some Radical by Contradiction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I’ve consistently been made to solve a rather absurd number of problems that involve proving the irrationality of some radical (Nth Root of X) by Contradiction, and since these problems often use a very similar method of proving irrationality (assuming the radical is equal to a fraction in simplest form, then proving that the Numerator and Denominator have some common multiple.

However, I was wondering if there exists some absolute definitive template to solve such a question, solved exclusively in variables to which numbers can be substituted. I do understand the naïveté of my question but I would greatly appreciate it if someone may explain this exists.

As a side note: I have attempted to do this by stating:

$$\mathrm{N^{th}-Root}(x) = \frac{a}{b}$$

$$x = \frac{a^n}{b^n}$$

$(b^n)x = (a^n)$, thereby proving that $a^n$ is a multiple of $b^n$, but I’ve gotten stuck. Again, I do not know what I am doing and would appreciate any help or explanation!

Comment: You could do this: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Nth_Root_of_Integer_is_Integer_or_Irrational

Comment: See the linked dupes (and their linkls) for most of the common methods.

Comment: "that a^n is a multiple of b^n, but I’ve gotten stuck"  .... Hint:  Assume $\frac ab$ is in lowest terms.  SO if $a^n$ is a multiple $b^n$ but $a$ and $b$ have no factors in common......  [But or you assuming $x$ is an integer?]

Comment: Also note $\sqrt{36}$ is *not* irrational.  Kinda important that you take the counter examples into accont.  If $\sqrt{36} =\frac ab$ then $b^2\cdot 36 =a^2$ and ... what becomes of that.